# Java game program: shooting the missile

Tags: java, drawing

I'm trying to write a program of a simple computer game. I'm having trouble getting the "missile" or "bullet" to shoot out of the red canon.

I think my problem is the boolean part. I'm fairly new to coding you see.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

right and left arrows move the canon right and left, home and page up keys rotate the stick on the canon, and the up arrow is supposed to make the missile fire.

Here is my code so far: as you can see, the missile only blinks when you hit the up arrow

```
    // This program is a simple video game that allows the user to 
    // attempt to indirectly shoot at a target, attempting to hit it. 


    //importing graphics
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Project2 {

      public static final int SLEEP_TIME = 50;

      // class constants below

      // key movements
      public static final int KEY_SPACE = 32;
      public static final int KEY_PAGE_UP = 33;
      public static final int  KEY_HOME = 36;
      public static final int  KEY_LEFT_ARROW = 37;
      public static final int KEY_UP_ARROW = 38;
      public static final int  KEY_RIGHT_ARROW = 39;
      public static final int  KEY_DOWN_ARROW = 40;

      // panel size set here
      public static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 300;
      public static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 300; 

      // The shooter 
      public static int SHOOTER_X;
      public static final int SHOOTER_Y = PANEL_HEIGHT-30;
      public static final int SHOOTER_SIZE = 20;
      public static final int SHOOTER_INITIAL_X = 140;

      // The target
      public static int TARGET_X = 140;
      public static final int TARGET_Y = PANEL_HEIGHT-280;
      public static final int TARGET_SIZE = 20;
      public static final int TARGET_INITIAL_X = 140;

      // The gun 
      public static int GUN_SIZE = 10;
      public static int Gun_Position_X = 0; 
      public static int Gun_Position_Y =PANEL_HEIGHT - GUN_SIZE;
      public static int Gun_Initial_X = 0;

      // The missile
      public static final int MISSILE_SIZE = 4;
      public static double MISSILE_SPEED = 0.1;
      public static double missileDeltaX = 0;        
      public static double missileDeltaY = 0;      
      public static int missilePositionX = PANEL_WIDTH / 2; 
      public static int missilePositionY = PANEL_HEIGHT - 25; 
      public static boolean missileActive;



      //color constants 
      public static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
      public static final Color SHOOTER_COLOR = Color.RED;
      public static final Color TARGET_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
      public static final Color MISSILE_COLOR = Color.BLACK;


      //main method
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics( ); 
        initialize();
        reset(g);
        startGame(panel, g);
      }

      //starts up the game and calls the methods
      public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
          panel.sleep(50);

          drawAll(g);
          moveMissile(g, missileDeltaX);
          drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
          drawTarget(g, TARGET_COLOR);
          handleKeys(panel,g);

        }
      }

      // states my name and the project number in black
      public static void drawAll(Graphics g) {          
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);      
        g.drawString("Project 2 by Kathryn Johnston",10,15);  
      } 

      public static void initialize(){
        //int SHOOTER_X = SHOOTER_INITIAL_X;
        boolean missileActive = false;
      }


    //draws the shooter
      public static void drawShooter(Graphics g, Color c) {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(SHOOTER_X, SHOOTER_Y, SHOOTER_SIZE, SHOOTER_SIZE);
        g.drawLine(Gun_Position_X+(SHOOTER_X+10), Gun_Position_Y - 30, SHOOTER_X+10, Gun_Position_Y-10);
      }

      //draws the target
      public static void drawTarget(Graphics g, Color c) {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(TARGET_X, TARGET_Y, TARGET_SIZE, TARGET_SIZE);
        g.drawLine(TARGET_X-10,TARGET_Y+30,TARGET_X+30,TARGET_Y+30); 
      }

    //input
      public static void handleKeys(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
        int keyCode = panel.getKeyCode();   
        if (keyCode == KEY_SPACE)
          reset(g);   
        else if (keyCode == KEY_RIGHT_ARROW){
          moveShooter(g,1);
          moveMissile(g,1);
        }
        else if (keyCode == KEY_LEFT_ARROW){
          moveShooter(g,-1);
          moveMissile(g,-1);
        }
        else if (keyCode == KEY_HOME)
          moveGun(g,-1);
        else if (keyCode == KEY_PAGE_UP)
          moveGun(g,1);    
        else if (keyCode == KEY_UP_ARROW){       
          shootMissile(g);
          boolean missileActive = true;
        }
      }

      // moves the shooter and re draws the background
      public static void  moveShooter(Graphics g, int deltaX) {    
        drawShooter(g, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        SHOOTER_X += deltaX;    
        if (SHOOTER_X < -SHOOTER_SIZE/2)
          SHOOTER_X = -SHOOTER_SIZE/2;
        if (SHOOTER_X >= PANEL_WIDTH - SHOOTER_SIZE/2)
          SHOOTER_X = PANEL_WIDTH - SHOOTER_SIZE/2 - 1;    
        drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
      }

    // moves the gun
      public static void moveGun(Graphics g, int deltaX) {    
        drawShooter(g, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        Gun_Position_X += deltaX;    
        if (Gun_Position_X < -GUN_SIZE)
          Gun_Position_X = -GUN_SIZE;
        if (Gun_Position_X > PANEL_WIDTH - GUN_SIZE/2)
          Gun_Position_X = PANEL_WIDTH - GUN_SIZE/2 - 1;    
        drawShooter(g, SHOOTER_COLOR);
      }


      //fires the missle
      public static void shootMissile(Graphics g) {
        moveMissile(g, missileDeltaX);
        missilePositionY += missileDeltaY;    
        if (missilePositionY < -MISSILE_SIZE)
          missilePositionY = -MISSILE_SIZE;
        if (missilePositionY > PANEL_HEIGHT - MISSILE_SIZE/2)
          missilePositionY = PANEL_HEIGHT - MISSILE_SIZE/2 - 1;    
        drawMissile(g, MISSILE_COLOR);  

      }

      //moves the missle
      public static void moveMissile(Graphics g, double missileDeltaX) {
        drawMissile(g, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        missilePositionX += missileDeltaX;    
        if (missilePositionX < -MISSILE_SIZE)
          missilePositionX = -MISSILE_SIZE;
        if (missilePositionX > PANEL_WIDTH - MISSILE_SIZE/2)
          missilePositionX = PANEL_WIDTH - MISSILE_SIZE/2 - 1;    
        drawMissile(g, MISSILE_COLOR);   
      }


      //draws the missle
      public static void drawMissile(Graphics g, Color c) {
        missilePositionX -= - missileDeltaY * MISSILE_SPEED;
        missilePositionY -= missileDeltaX * MISSILE_SPEED;   
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(missilePositionX, missilePositionY, MISSILE_SIZE, MISSILE_SIZE);  
      }

      // reset method. this will reset everything's position
      public static void reset(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0,0,PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT);
        SHOOTER_X = SHOOTER_INITIAL_X;
        Gun_Position_X = Gun_Initial_X;
        drawShooter(g,SHOOTER_COLOR);
      }    

    }
```

Comment: You're doing Graphics wrong by using a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. If this is Swing, draw the correct way in a Swing component's paintComponent method as the tutorials and many answers on this site will show you. You're code is also grossly over-using the static modifier suggesting that a re-write is in order to try to make this code more OOP compliant. Consider breaking this code into several independently testable classes as well which will make debugging easier for you and for us.

Answer (score 2):

I found this code:

```
 public static void initialize(){
    boolean missileActive = false;
  }
```

It should be:

```
public static void initialize(){
    missileActive = false;
  }
```

You were creating a `boolean` that is local to that method.

---

I'm also certain that you don't need to declare numeric constants for the keys. See [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: You are correct with what you have found and with your suggestion, but please don't deface the OP's code with your edits, if they are not part of the original code. 1+ for the answer though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It wasn't my intention to deface the code. It needs to be peer-reviewed anyway. I actually started by removing superfluous code, found this line, and realized the problem.